# to enact that coming together

Tags: meaning-in-context

can you help me about the exact meaning of the following passage?

> He had called on university communities nationwide to mix with
>   ordinary people to form a jameeh’e tohidi, or unitary Islamic
>   paradigm.His message, which had leftist undertones, resonated strongly
>   with the young people, who poured out in the streets **to enact that
>   coming together**.

The words in bold are problematic.
Thanks a million.

Comment: The religious texts are always written in some rhetorical, old English. I think instead of asking it here, asking this question at www.islam.stackexchange.com will be much helpful.

Comment: @Riya Agarwal  It isn't some rhetorical, old English! It's just ordinary, plain English.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of it is "He had called on them to mix with ordinary people. The students liked what he said and gathered on the streets to **do as he had asked."**

**To enact** means to put into action, or to carry out, or to perform. The word **that** is used here as a determiner, so **that coming together** means *the mixing (or associating) which he had called for*.